# How did the inscription dome of rock survive

Tags: history

How come that the inscription of dome of rock survived?

The building was damaged in 808 and 846 CE, collapsed in earthquake in 1015CE and 1033CE. There was a crusade in 1099 and dome of rock become a Catholic church.

I would have really thought that Muhammad is a title of Jesus as christian say (nauzubillah) as my iman is weak,but as it was Catholic church the divinity of Jesus was well established in 11 CE, so noway they would have let a inscription survive if it denies his divinity...

Even the name of abbasid Khalifa Mamun survived that was their enemy. We can't say that that was also Jesus title.

Was this inscription in an other place and after Muslim reconquered the Dome of rock they put this inscription there?

Comment: Please clarify what is the relation of your question and the topic of this site. I don't see any.

Comment: I want know how the inscription survived, when it became a church,was not church supposed to destroy anything that  deny Jesus's divinity and moreover Abbasid Khalifa's name also survived,how?Why church didn’t demolish those inscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

The building was severely damaged by earthquakes in 808 and again in 846. The dome collapsed in an earthquake in 1015 and was rebuilt in 1022–23. The mosaics on the drum were repaired in 1027–28. The earthquake of 1033 resulted in the introduction of wooden beams to enforce the dome.

For detail see this: [Abbasids and Fatimids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dome_of_the_Rock#:%7E:text=Parts%20of%20the%20Dome%20of,taken%20place%20over%20previous%20years.)

Comment: No one have any idea???